# Why log4j2 prints double stacktrace when using %replace?

Tags: log4j

My use case is to get rid of the new lines in the stacktrace. Unfortunately the separator ([link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)) doesn't work because it leaves one - and exaclty one - new line in the trace for some reason.

So what I try is to apply the replace pipe.

```
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = { %-5level %logger{36} - %message}%n
```

**result:** prints each stacktrace line into a new line

```
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = { %-5level %logger{36} - %message %replace{%xThrowable}{[\r\n]+}{}}%n
```

**result:** Succesfully removes the new lines and print the stack trace, however it will print it also second time with the new lines still in

My solution:

```
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = { %-5level %logger{36} - %message %xThrowable{0} %replace{%xThrowable}{[\r\n]+}{}}%n
```

**result:** Prints the stacktrace without the new lines and only once.

What is going on?

Why the replace command doubles the stacktrace? And why %xThrowable{0} removes only one stacktrace and not all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PatternLayout will print the stacktrace automatically unless it detects one of the throwable conversion specifiers in the pattern. My guess is that it is not looking for the throwable conversion specifier being inside of another conversion specifier. Your workaround is the proper way to handle this.